# Popover Control Background Color Odd Behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipopover

So in my app I have a popover control with an embedded navigation control.  In different parts of the navigation stack, I want the popover to be different colors depending on where the user is.  The weird thing is sometimes setting the popover background color makes this terrible looking box around it, sometimes it doesn't.  It looks like this:

[image]

This is the look I am trying to get:

[image]

It seems if I change the background color before displaying the popover it seems to work and transition correctly, but if I don't set the popover color before showing it, then change it after it has been shown it has the box effect.  I've also noticed other cases where it seems to happen randomly, but I can't really explain what is causing it (my real app is much more complex than this demo).  Here is the relevant code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(innerButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [b setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    [vc.view addSubview:b];
    _innerNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    _popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_innerNav];

    //If this line is here, everything works fine
    _popOver.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [_popOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    //If this line is here (and the above line is commented out), the transition will look wrong
    //_popOver.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}

-(void)innerButtonPressed {
    _controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(test) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [b setTitle:@"Make Purple" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
    [_controller.view addSubview:b];
    [_popOver setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [_innerNav pushViewController:_controller animated:YES];
}

-(void)test{
    _popOver.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
}
```

Any idea what is causing this issue?  And what steps to safely update the background color of a popover without ever getting into this state?  I have a full project demonstrating the problem, I thought you could attach projects to questions but apparently you cannot.  If someone wants it I can probably host it somewhere.

Comment: Are you seeing this issue on the Simulator or a device (or both)?

Comment: I'm seeing this on both the simulator and a device

Comment: If you host the project somewhere I will download it and see if I get the same issue. I don't have any definitive ideas, but am certainly willing to take a look it you want.

Comment: Any idea what the easiest place to post and link to it is?

Comment: I normally use GitHub or drobbox (with a public link).

Comment: Ok I edited in a link to drop box

Comment: Nevermind that link doesn't seem to work, I'll post it to github when I get home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at your sample project, Apple's ["Popover Controllers in iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/samplecode/Popovers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010436) sample project, perusing [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/), and trying a few different things I have come to the following observations:

- The `UIPopoverController` only exhibits this odd behavior when it is presented without a valid value for the `backgroundColor` property. From this I am guessing that since `UIPopoverController`'s `backgroundColor` property is `nil` by default it must use different drawing code than when the `backgroundColor` property is valid.
- Triggering some sort of redraw (e.x. Setting `popoverContentSize`) will get the colored box overlay to go away (it looks like it clips a color layer).

Conclusion: For the time being I would set a `backgroundColor` prior to the `UIPopoverController` being presented and then update it as needed.  If this is not an option try updating the `UIPopoverController` such that it redraws (As a note: I was not able to get this to look good and it seems hacky).  Lastly, I would [report it as a bug](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to apple.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Interestingly enough setting it to nil gives the frost glass look, which I wanted on some transitions, and a set background color on others, but perhaps something like calling `LayoutIfNeeded` when changing it might be all I need to do

Comment: I tried `layoutIfNeeded`, but it did not work. Since `UIPopoverController` is a NSObject and not a UIView it cannot call `layoutIfNeeded` (or other similar view methods), so I tried calling it on `_popOver.contentViewController.view`, naturally this did not work since the view is not what needs to be redrawn.

Comment: After thinking over your comment more, I realized you could 1) set the `backgroundColor` to an arbitrary color and then 2) right after presenting the `UIPopoverController` set the `backgroundColor` to `nil`. I tried this and once this is done you can set and `nil` the `backgroundColor` property all you want and the draw error will not occur. Again, it is not idea, but it works until Apple fixes this bug.

Comment: Yeah I noticed I could do that as well, but it only seems to work in my demo project not in my actual project =(.  My actual project attempts to change the background color in the `willShowViewController` of the inner nav controller which also has strange results.

Answer (score 1):

UIPopoverController is now deprecated. I found a similar issue when updating it to use the new *popoverPresentationController*. In the past I was able to set the `backgroundColor` of UIPopoverController before presenting. The popover presentation controller also has a backgroundColor property but didn't work like it did before where I could assign it before presentation. To get it to work I had to assign it after it starts presenting for some reason:

```
contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[[self presentViewController:contentViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    // completion code
}];
contentViewController.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

For your particular scenario where you are changing the background color after presentation is finished I don't think you'd be able to do that by just changing the popoverPresentationController's backgroundColor. The only solution I can think of is to dismiss and re-present the popover without animating:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

    [[self presentViewController:contentViewController animated:NO completion:^{
        // completion code
    }];
    contentViewController.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

}];
```